# Reapply for a UK visitor visa; do I really need to send all the documents again?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

After checking the reasons why my wife has been refused a visa, our mistake was not providing some additional documents. She would like to reapply.

Do we need to send all the documents again with her application to VFS, or can we just send the documents needed to satisfy the points on the refusal letter?

The ECO have kept copies of payslips, bank statement and rental contract.

Comment: Surely you didn't send your *only* copy of these documents?

Comment: no they were copies , she still has the originals.

Comment: A fresh application should be complete and contain all the necessary evidence.

Answer (score 2):

While reapplying is the term used, you're actually making a new application, not amending a previous one with the addition of missing or supplemental information. It would oversight to omit required information, and would put your application in jeopardy of a refusal.

See whether the [UK Visa & Immigration supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) would help; it has a checklist of everything needed (and what isn't).